# Get a list of lines in a set of files at certain locations, visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a list of files and line numbers with flaws from some auto generated code, and I want to check to see if they are all similar errors. Is there a way I can get visual studio to just straight show me all the lines next to each other like it does when you do a Find All in a solution?
for example I have:

```
File1.cs line 7
File1.cs line 17
File1.cs line 23
File2.cs line 7
File2.cs line 14
File3.cs line 16
File4.cs line 7
```

and I want to see the lines of code there for that. Is there a way anyone knows about?

Answer (score 0):

So I wrote a quick linqpad script for this rather than using visual studio, but for prosperity here is the vital function:

```
string getLine(path,line){
    return File.ReadLines(path).Skip(line-1).Take(1).First();
}
```